# Segmentation fault 11 is this related to Obj-C-bridge.h?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm migrating to Swift 3.0 and keep coming across the Segmentation fault 11:

```
CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
    cd "/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app"
    export DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    export SDKROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk
    export TOOLCHAINS=com.apple.dt.toolchain.XcodeDefault
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc -incremental -module-name SA_Dev -Onone -D COCOAPODS -DDEV -DDEBUG -sdk /......./MyApp\ DEV.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SA_Dev-Swift.h -import-objc-header /Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp\ Dev/ios-app/MyApp/Obj-C-bridge.h -Xcc -working-directory/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp\ Dev/ios-app

<unknown>:0: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
<unknown>:0: error: compile command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
<unknown>:0: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
<unknown>:0: error: compile command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
<unknown>:0: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
<unknown>:0: error: compile command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
<unknown>:0: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
<unknown>:0: error: compile command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
```

The long path ends with:

`SA_Dev-Swift.h -import-objc-header /Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp\ Dev/ios-app/MyApp/Obj-C-bridge.h -Xcc -working-directory/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp\ Dev/ios-app`

Is this likely to be an issue with either my `Obj-C-bridge.h` or pods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in the SWIFT compiler, which Apple has to fix. You should [report](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/) it to Apple.

Until Apple has fixed the bug, you should try to isolate the piece that triggers the bug and then make some changes so the bug isn't triggered. Sometimes, changing the order of a few things or changing the white space is enough. Sometimes, you have to remove the triggering code and replace it with an alternative implementation.

And yes, the place to start is `Obj-C-bridge.h`. Remove everything there and then start to add things piece by piece until you have identified the triggering code or line.

Comment: In my case XCODE basically isn't doing any error highlighting when changing files. In the left panel though I can see some Buildtime issues. I work though them and get to the last one. If I make any change or even delete the code end up on the seg error.

Comment: It sure will be a very cumbersome investigation. Since the bridge file is affected, you basically need to rebuild the entire project every time you make a change to isolate the problem. And since removed lines in the bridge file affect a lot of other code, it's very difficult to find cut through all the errors and check if the compiler crashed, which is the only relevant error at the moment.

Comment: What a nightmare. Thanks for your advice.